# Discussion? Is there a place for it?

Tags: support

I am currently a high school student and self studying mathematics and at some points I feel as if I would like to initiate a general discussion regarding mathematics. Is there a place for these types of post on this site?

Comment: The [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) is probably the best place for this.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is "not really". For better or worse, the design of this site is intended to avoid lengthy discussions, and to encourage a question and answer format instead.

However, you can get a lot out of the site by using it in a certain way. As you are learning from other resources (particularly, textbooks), take note of specific problems you don't understand. If you are unable to solve them yourself, ask about them, with special care to explain which parts are giving you trouble. Then, the answers will be able to discuss those parts, and they often contain good insight into what is going on.

The key to getting info out of answers is to put work into the question. Don't just ask "why is this true?". Instead, think through it yourself, clarify what you know and don't know, and then describe that in the question. This will help other people write answers that are particularly relevant to you.